# Consider $Y = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty\}$ and $X = \{ \frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{0\}$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Consider $Y = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty\}$ and $X = \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{0\}$

Consider $X$ with usual metric and let us consider a bijective map $f:Y \mapsto X$ where $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(\infty) = 0 $.

We can define a metric on $Y$ using the metric on $X$ as $d_Y(m,n) = |f({m}) - f({n})|$.

> What are the open sets in this metric space?

**My claim is that the singletons are open in $Y$ except $\{\infty\}$**

I am having  a trouble to write the proof. Here's what I have attempted:

Let us consider the open ball $B_{d_Y}(m;\epsilon)$.

We choose $\epsilon = min\{|\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+1}|,|\frac{1}{m-1} - \frac{1}{m}|\}$.

Let us consider $m' \in B_{d_Y}(m;\epsilon)$.

Since $m' \in \mathbb{N}$

Case $1:$ Assume that $m' > m$ then $\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m'} < \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+1}$.Then we can conclude that $\frac{1}{m'} > \frac{1}{m+1}$ and $m'<m+1$. Hence $m<m'<m+1$ which is not possible.

Case $2:$ Assume that $m' < m$ then $\frac{1}{m'} - \frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{m-1} - \frac{1}{m}$.Then we can conclude that $\frac{1}{m'} < \frac{1}{m-1}$ and $m'>m-1$. Hence $m-1<m'<m$ which is not possible.

*So the singletons are open.*

Let us consider a ball of the form $B_{d_Y}(\infty;\epsilon)$. Then we know that if $y \in B_{d_Y}(\infty;\epsilon)$ then $d_Y(y,\infty) < \epsilon \implies |\frac{1}{y}| < \epsilon$ .Then we know that by archimedian property this holds.

*$\{\infty\}$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$*

> I was trying to find a proper reason as to why this is happening.Since $f$ defined is a bijective map which I guess is also a continuous map(a hoemeomorphism?). We know that $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is open in $X$ hence $f^{-1}(\{\frac{1}{n}\})$ is open in $Y$.Also $\{0\}$ is not open in $X$ hence $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is not open in $Y$. Is this way of explaining things correct?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, that's what I meant

Comment: In $X$ all open sets containing $0$ contain all but finitely many of the $\frac1n$. The same holds in $Y$: all open sets containing $\infty$ contain all but finitely of the $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:(Y,d_Y) \to (X,d)$ is an isometry by definition. Here $d$ is the usual metric on $X$ inherited from $\Bbb R$. Also a bijection so it's a homeomorphism.

Any topological fact about $X$ will also be true of $Y$ and vice versa. $X$ is compact and so is $Y$. All points in $X$ except $0$ are isolated and the same is true for all points except $\infty$ in $Y$ etc. $X$ and $Y$ are both instances of the one point-compactification of a countable and discrete space.

Comment: What is isometry?

Comment: A map between metric spaces that preserves distances; $d_X(x,x') = d_Y(f(x), f(x'))$ for all $x,x'$. @ThirstForMaths

Comment: So any isometry is a continuous map ? How do I prove this?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths take $\delta=\epsilon$ for all points.

Comment: Yes, I understood the reason now..Thank you :)

Comment: So, whenever we have an isometry it is enough to find the open sets $U$ in $X$ taking the inverse $f^{-1}(U)$ will give me the open sets in $Y$ and this is an iff condition

Comment: @ThirstForMaths yes for any homeomorphism.